# ibatis spring java.lang.NoSuchMethodError com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse

Tags: java, spring, exception, weblogic, mybatis

i am using spring 3.2.0 with ibatis 2.3.4 in weblogic 10.3.6
while deploying in weblogic.

I am getting this NoSuchMethodError as below:

```
User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gatewayService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-granite-webservice.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoIPInventory' while setting bean property 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoIPInventory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-ip-ibatis-db.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlMapClient' while setting bean property 'sqlMapClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-ip-ibatis-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lcom/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapClient;.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gatewayService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-granite-webservice.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoIPInventory' while setting bean property 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoIPInventory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-ip-ibatis-db.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlMapClient' while setting bean property 'sqlMapClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-ip-ibatis-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lcom/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapClient;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoIPInventory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-ip-ibatis-db.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlMapClient' while setting bean property 'sqlMapClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-ip-ibatis-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lcom/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapClient;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-ip-ibatis-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lcom/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapClient;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lcom/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapClient;
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:339)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Post your code and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Spring 3.2 is not compatible with iBatis 2.3.4.

In [iBatis 2.3.4 SqlMapConfigParser](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/ibatis/sqlmap/engine/builder/xml/SqlMapConfigParser.java.html) has no method #parse(InputStream, Properties), but in newer version [myBatis 2.3.5](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/mybatis/mybatis/2.3.5/mybatis-2.3.5-sources.jar!/com/ibatis/sqlmap/engine/builder/xml/SqlMapConfigParser.java?format=ok) it is exist.

Probably problem also in [MyBatis-Spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/) library version.

Nevertheless you should update version of myBatis or find appropriate version of Spring or Spring-iBatis integration.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have ibatis  jar file and mysql-connector jar file in your project. and your controller class name should not be controller.java

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have ibatis jar file and mysql-connector jar file in your project. and your controller class name should not be controller.java

your sqlmap namespace name should be unique for each sqlmap file which you have written in sqlMapConfig.xml

In your sqlmap file, all tag should be clearly defined. you should mention parameterClass and resultClass. Must not leave as empty one, like this.

select id="sampleid" parameterClass="" resultClass=""

Your query

select id="sampleid"

Your quer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ibatis jar which you are using does not have parse method with those arguments. Decompile and see if the jar has parse the method which code is looking for.